# Using a variable as global

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with a library for performing optimization over graphs. Since the code for this library goes completely over my head I gave up on trying to adapt it to my own needs. One of its functions is used to compute a smoothness penalty and accepts only four parameters. However I would need an additional parameter (a matrix containing many values) in order to properly calculate the penalty value. The matrix is originally stored as a Mat (opencv) object and then loaded so I can't just declare it global. Is there any way to take this variable and make it accessible to all methods that may need it?

Comment: Please explain "The matrix is originally stored as a Mat (opencv) object and then loaded so I can't just declare it global".

Comment: The data I need exists as a yml file. This, when loaded with the opencv library outputs a Mat object. In my (admittedly brief) experience with c++ I have only used global variables when they were something simple, such as a number, or a string. So I don't know how I can take this object after loading it and make it public. I hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: You should post a little code sample to show your issue. And yes, you can define a global and assign to it later (it's not a really nice design, though).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was being too hasty and as expected the "quick and dirty" solution turned out horribly. As Miki said I could declare the global variable first and then set the value. While this worked it was not something that looked good. So I took some time and saw that the function I needed could receive a struct with the necessary data allowing me to do what I needed without the bad design.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing the code, I understand you want a global variable that gives accessable to method. One way is to declare a Singleton that holds the Pointer to the real `Mat struct`.

When the `Mat struct` is created, you pass the pointer of it to the Singleton. On deletion of the `Mat struct`, you tell the Singleton to reset. E.g.

```
class MatSingleton
{
public:
   MatSingleton() : pMatInstance(nullptr) {}
   ~MatSingleton() {}

   static MatSingleton& GetInstance()
   {
      static MatSingleton instance;
      return instance;
   }

   bool IsMatAvailable()
   {
      return pMatInstance != nullptr;
   }

   void SetMat(Mat *pMat) { pMatInstance = pMat; }
   Mat* GetMat() const { return pMatInstance; }

private:
   Mat      *pMatInstance;
};

[...]    

// Load and fill LoadedMatStruct and inform the Singleton
MatSingleton::GetInstance().SetMat( &LoadedMatStruct );


// check if the Mat structure can be accessed
if (MatSingleton::GetInstance().IsMatAvailable())
{
   // do smth. with Mat
   Mat *pMatInstance = MatSingleton::GetInstance().GetMat();
}


// Somewhere else in the code where the Mat structe is destroyed, it is necessary to inform the Singleton
MatSingleton::GetInstance().SetMat( nullptr );
```

Note: This demo code is not thread safe. It should just illustrate the idea.

Comment: You don't need a singleton to do this, let alone pointers to cv::Mat objects. You should really avoid that, since you're very likely to break internal reference counter consistency

Comment: @Miki: Thanks for your point. If cv::Mat already is a reference counted object, the I totally agree that there is no need for a helper Singleton in this case.